# Do I need to add a name to the input if I am already adding a formControlName?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In the following example, name seems redundant.

```
<label for="first-name">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control"
                    formControlName="firstName"
                    type="text"
                    id="first-name"
                    name="firstName"
                    maxlength=53>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is redundant. Not only that but I'd not use name when using reactive forms (indicated by using "formControlName" in your question) following the examples in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#adding-a-basic-form-control

If you were using 2-way binding this **is** required:

> When you use [(ngModel)] on an element, you must define a name attribute for that element.

https://angular.io/guide/forms#naming-control-elements

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I started working on a project, and I saw formControlName AND name in all inputs. I just wanted to double check before removing the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there is at least one caveat here: if you are using radio buttons, you will not be able to tab between radio button groups if they do not have a `name` attribute explicitly set.

Setting a `formControlName` does not automatically add a `name` attribute to the rendered HTML, but a `name` attribute is required for accessibly navigable radio buttons.

So, there is some benefit explicitly setting a `name` attribute, especially with radio inputs.